# how to vertically and horizontally center a text within a container in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to vertically and horizontally center a text within a white container in flutter.

Code I used to generate the following example but it is not vertically centered. Any idea how to?

```
return Center(
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    width: 105,
    height: 105,
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Text(
          '1',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the `Text` widget is already centered vertically, but the text itself has some line height that makes it looks like there is some space on the top.

From the documentation of [`height`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/height.html) property of `TextStyle`:

[image: Text line height]

---

If you set the `height` to `1.1` for example, you can see it now looks centered:

```dart
Text(
  '1',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 100,
    height: 1.1,
  ),
)
```

[image]

---

References:

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/height.html

Comment: How did you get to value 1.1 and not 1 or 0.9? Is it visually or doc or calculation?

Comment: It really depends on the font you're using. You can find the perfect number visually, and once you get it you can always use that number because it's a multiplier to the font size so any font size changes in the future won't break it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      width: 105,
      height: 105,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(
          '1',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: solution is same as my example!

Comment: Look at your code again! Then run your code, run mine

Comment: I did run your solution but it provided the solve the problem.

Comment: @MKapp, not sure what you are saying, kindly elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Center` widget to align it center

```
Center(
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.amberAccent,
    width: 105,
    height: 105,
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
            '1',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

and you text is not center because `fontSize` is too large so decrease it

Comment: I cannot decrease the fontSize (this is a requirement). Therefore the solution does not work!

Comment: give height to font `height: 1`